# React webpack development configuration with html-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I am currently having a situation with my `React` app specifically in the development environment. I am currently creating a template for quickly building a [react-landing-page](https://github.com/Nappstir/react-landing-page). This obviously does not have `redux` but can be wired in if an individual finds the need for it.

Basically I'm running into an inconvenient "error" when wanting to build my project for production. I am forcing the developer to have to remove the `bunlde.js` script tag from `src/index.html` when building for prod, and in return they have to reimplement the script tag when wanting to work in dev. Now the app will still run in production, but you will receive a console log error if the script tag is not removed: [image]
Now I know that I can remove my `bundle.js` script tag from `src/index.html` and have it injected through [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin), thus resolving the issue altogether. However, when I do that I run into a new issue. That issue being when/if I refresh the page on any other path besides root... for example: `http://localhost:3000/about`, it will return an empty page because `bundle.js` script only gets injected at the root level on page load. It does not on any other page.

Thus my question would be how to get `hmtl-webpack-plugin` to work in my dev environment so that I do not have to force an individual to manually put in and take out the `bundle.js` tag?

Take a look at the repo, maybe I am missing something here. Any suggestions or time helping me resolve this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a single-page app? If so the server should be configured to route all requests to root, if you're using something like react-router.

Comment: Could you provide the example code for script tag injected through html-webpack-plugin? It will be helpful to verify the answer on my part.

Comment: @jered Yes this is a SPA. I am using react-router and I am configuring all requests to root. Maybe I am missing something if you can see it in the source code. I have added the link to the repo to the `react-landing-page` link in the question.

Comment: @Upasana You can check out the repo by clicking on the `react-landing-page` link provided in the original question. As for the implementation of `html-webpack-plugin`, I would perform adding it by simply: 

new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
 template: 'src/index.html',
 inject: true
}). Similar to how I did it in the Prod configuration, without the `chunks, chunksSortMode and minify` properties. The output obviously being `bundle.js`